# Convert recorded audio files on Android to text

Tags: android, cmusphinx

I am recoding my call into mp3 format i want to change the audio files in to text is it possible in android or using sphinx.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to convert using CMUSphinx API. For more details please read the tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial. You just need to setup engine and feed it the audio.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input w e will check it i think it would be  another question is it possible to to convert audio file to text using sphinks.

Comment: It is obviously possible to do that, it's worth to avoid to ask too simple questions. This site recommends questions targetted to a specific problem. See for details http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's speech to text api to convert audio, but it only accepts limited formats, like flac.
You can also try the [javascript port of Sphinx](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js/tree/master/doc/AudioRecorder) as that will save you the extra task of performing the same in Java and setting up a webservice to interact with your android code.